# jQuery - how to assign click() to an element inside html that was loaded using load()

Tags: jquery

I'm a novice at jQuery, so go easy on me!

I'd like to assign a click() function to an element inside a div.  The trouble is that the element has been loaded from an external html source.

In other words, I'm loading a "close" button inside a div that should hide the div itself.

The result I'm getting is that the close button does nothing when clicked.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

index.html:

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>

   <div id="container"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

load.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#container').load('content.html');
});
```

content.html

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>

   <div id="close"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

close.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#close").click(function(){
        $("#container").hide(0);    
    });
});
```

Comment: Where are you loading `close.js`?

Comment: i'm loading close.js in index.html, but i've tried loading it in both index.html and content.html, still no dice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `on()`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#container").on('click', '#close', function(){
        $("#container").hide(0);    
    });
});
```

Comment: yep. you got it right - it worked.  THANKS!